# Change from frequent to recent items in explorer jump list

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

I know it's possible, but I can't for the life of me figure out how I did it... In a fresh Windows 7 install, the explorer jump list shows frequent items. There is a way to change it to show recent items instead, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right-click the **Start** button, click **Properties**.
2. On the **Start menu** tab, remove the tick from **Store and display recently opened items in the Start menu and the taskbar** (the second checkbox) and click **OK**. Now the *Frequent* section will disappear from the jump list.
3. Go back to the same dialog and re-tick the checkbox.

Now the jump list will still be empty, but as you start using the Explorer, it will be populated with the recent items.

Comment: You may have to restart after enabling again (or at least log out and then in) in order to start indexing again. I'm not sure. In any case, it doesn't work instantly.

Comment: It works instantly for me on Windows 8.1 (no reboot/logout)